# Php break the ul li

Tags: php

I am showing images in php in ul list. I want to show 5 li in my ul then 2 li and after that again 5 li.I am using this code but it is showing 5 li every row.

```
 <?php
  $data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

  $break_after = 5;

  $counter = 0;   
 $totalNumber = count($data);                    
 foreach ($data as $item) 
 {
if ($counter % $break_after == 0) 
{
    echo '<ul>';
}

echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';    

if ($counter % $break_after == ($break_after-1) || $counter ==   $totalNumber-1) {
    echo '</ul>';
}
++$counter;

}
```

- dfff
- fdfddf
- fdfd
- ffd
- fdfd

- fddf
- dfdf

- fddf
- dfdf
- dfdf
- fddf
- fddf

- fdfd
- fddf
- fddf
- fdfd
- fddf

Comment: Could you paste the expected HTML output so it is clearer what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to show five li in first ul then 2 li in second ul and again five li tags for all next ul tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want use the following:

```
<?php
  $data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22);
 $total = count($data);
 foreach ($data as $index => $item)
 {
  if ($index == 0 || $index == 5 || $index == 7 || ($index > 8 && ($index - 2) % 5 == 0))
  {
    echo '<ul>';
  }
  echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
  if ($index == 4 || $index == 6 || $index == $total - 1 || ($index > 6 && ($index - 2) % 5 == 4)) {
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solution might help you :
When you want a break after 5,2,5 Y not take that an array array(5,2,5) instead of just break_after=5.  **break_after=5** will breake the ul at every 5 intervals. I have some change in logic for you :

```
 $data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

  $break_after = array(5,2,5);

  $counter = 0;   
  $break_key=0;
  $totalNumber = count($data);                    
  foreach ($data as $item){
    if ($counter % $break_after[$break_key] == 0){
        echo '<ul>';
    }

    echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';    

    if ($counter % $break_after[$break_key] == ($break_after[$break_key]-1) || $counter ==   $totalNumber-1) {
        echo '</ul>';
        ++$break_key;
        $counter = 0;
    }else{
    ++$counter;
    }
  }
```

Output for same is :

```
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li></ul>

<ul><li>6</li><li>7</li></ul>

<ul><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same answer as varunsinghal and Vivek Tankaria, but refactored to separate the logic and the view:

```
<?php
    $pattern = [5, 2, 5, 5];
    $data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
    if (count($data) < array_sum($pattern)) {
        throw new Exception('Please provide at least the same amount of data as lines required in the pattern');
    }
?>

<?php foreach ($pattern as $limit): ?>
<ul>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++): ?>
    <li><?= $data[$i]; ?></li>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

***For multiple values in array.***

```
 $data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36);

 $break_after = array(5,2,5);

 $counter = 0;   

 $break_key=0;

 $totalNumber = count($data);                    

 foreach ($data as $item){
    if ($counter % $break_after[$break_key] == 0){
        echo '<ul>';
    }

    echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';    

    if ($counter % $break_after[$break_key] == ($break_after[$break_key]-1)) {
        echo '</ul>';
        ++$break_key;
        if(count($break_after)==($break_key)){
            $break_key=0;
        }
        $counter = 0;
    }else{
        ++$counter;
    }
  }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic

```
<?php
    $data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
    $breakPoint=4;
    $ct=1;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($data as $k=>$v){
        echo '<li>'.$v.'</li>';
        if($breakPoint == $k && $ct==1){
            $breakPoint=$breakPoint+2;
            $ct=2;
            echo '</ul><br/><ul>';
        }elseIf($breakPoint == $k && $ct==2){
            $breakPoint=$breakPoint+5;
            $ct=1;
            echo '</ul><br/><ul>';
       }
   }
   echo '</ul>';
  ?>
```

Output:

1
2
3
4
5

6
7

8
9
10
11
12

Answer (score -2):

First break is at 5 so `$i` will be 4 then 2 elements more so `$i` will be 6. After this the break is required after every 5 elements, so we have 5+2+5 = 12 elements which gives `$i=11` So similarly other break points will be 11 16 21 26  31 36 and so on.

```
<ul>
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($data as $item){
echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
if($i==4 || $i==6 || $i==11 || $i==16 || $i==21 || $i==26){
echo '</ul><ul>';
}
$i++;
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: my all data is coming in one foreach loop.

Comment: Its not feasible to use 3 for loop for 1 single array. What if $data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24);

Will we write 6 for loop ? Not a good idea.

Comment: @VivekTankaria I have updated the code. Hope it take care of your concerns.